# Duplicate columns when displaying mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating a stylized table from mysql with php but for some reason it creates duplicate columns of my Date and Count.  Can someone help figure out why this is happening to me?  Thank you

```
<?php

include("dbconnect.php");   

$link=Connection();

$result = mysql_query(
                      "SELECT Date, Count
                      FROM testLocation 
                      WHERE Date 
                      BETWEEN '2016-04-10 00:01:11' AND '2016-04-23 00:01:11'"
                      ,$link
                      );


  if($result!==FALSE){
         echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
         echo '<tr><th>Date</th><th>Count</th></tr>';
         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
               echo '<tr>';
               foreach($row as $key=>$value1){
               echo '<td>', $value1,'</td>';
               }
               echo '<tr>';
         }
         echo '</table><br />';
         mysql_free_result($result);
         mysql_close();
      }
?>
```

Comment: Try to use `DISTINCT` in your sql.

Comment: Hi Reno, I unfortunately have already tried that and it did not work.

Comment: from the docs - [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) - *— Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both*. Default is both (ie. `MYSQL_BOTH`), so you are getting both the associative array and a numeric array. Change `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {` to `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {` **OR** `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {`

Comment: Sweet, Thank you Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off all, please try to change your code to MySQLi, now for your problem you need to know that `mysql_fetch_array` will return an array with associative and numeric keys. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or **FALSE** if there are no more rows. The type of returned array depends on how result_type is defined. By using **MYSQL_BOTH** (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices. Using **MYSQL_ASSOC**, you only get associative indices (as mysql_fetch_assoc() works), using **MYSQL_NUM**, you only get number indices (as mysql_fetch_row() works).

So to avoid duplicate data in your loop you need to use either of these three options:

```
// The important part here is to set the result type eg: MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_NUM. By defualt it is MYSQL_BOTH and thats your problem right now.
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC | MYSQL_NUM);

// Or this, it will return rows with associative indexes (keys are named after the column), eg: $row['Date']
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

// Or this, it will return rows with numeric indexes, eg: $row[0]
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```